# Fragment replace not working when using ChildFragmentManager in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I want to add a fragment as a **child** to another fragment
I am using **ChildFragmentManager**

Here is my [ChildFragmentManagerActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/R6YBW7ZT)
[ChildFragment.java](http://pastebin.com/vbWg0DhB)
[ParentFragment.java](http://pastebin.com/vdX57KwT)
 whose layouts are as as follows 
[activity_childfragmentmanager.xml](http://pastebin.com/YvMHK8xp)
[layout_parentfragment.xml](http://pastebin.com/W4A2Ap3p)
[layout_childfragment.xml](http://pastebin.com/b2qAAFJi)

I was able to add the **ParentFragment** successfully. Please check below image 
 [image: parent_fragment.png]

But when i try to add the **ChildFragment**, it is appearing as follows 
 [image: child_fragment]

**I want the child fragment to be added as a content by replacing the previous layout** 
**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: "I want the child fragment to be added as a content by replacing the previous layout." Can you explain it more clearly please? What is previous layout?

Comment: Hi koso Thanks for your comment. The red portion(**layout_parentfragment**) is the layout of **ParentFragment**. I am adding a child fragment to it. The blue portion(**layout_childfragment**) is the layout of **ChildFragment**. I want the blue to be replaced by red completely similar to a Fragment replace method. But it is just adding the ChildFragment instead of replacing it.

Comment: What about if you add frameLayout on the beginning of parent_layout with height=match_parent and visiblity=gone. And when you add your fragment to frameLayout, make that frameLayout visible, so it will cover whole parent fragment layout. I think you want to make that right?

Comment: Yes you are right! If i use FrameLayout and parent_layout height as match_parent it is working. But it is not working in 2 cases \n 1)** If layout height is set to "wrap_content". \n 2)If the parent layout is other than RelativeLayout or FrameLayout**.\n I want to solve the above two cases

Answer (score 5):

A transaction doesn't remove the views that already exist in the container that will be used for the transaction. To remove those views you need to wrap the initial content of the `ParentFragment` as a fragment and replace that by the child fragment(with a `replace` transaction and not an `add` transaction). I've made some changes to your code, check it out below:

ParentFragment:

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {

private static final int CONTAINER_ID = 0x2222;
private static final String INITIAL_FRAG = "initial_fragment";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FrameLayout wrapper = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    wrapper.setId(CONTAINER_ID);
    // look for our two possible fragments, if we don't find the
    // InitialContentFragment add it
    if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(INITIAL_FRAG) == null) {
        InitialContentFragment initContent = new InitialContentFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("text",
                "I'm the initial content fragment in the parent fragment");
        initContent.setArguments(args);
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(CONTAINER_ID, initContent, INITIAL_FRAG).commit();
    }
    return wrapper;
}

public void requestFragmentTransaction() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    ChildFragment childFragment = new ChildFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("text", "Hi I am Child Fragment");
    childFragment.setArguments(args);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(CONTAINER_ID, childFragment, "ChildFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

}

where the `InitialContentFragment` is:

```
public static class InitialContentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate the layout file that would normally be in the
        // ParentFragment at start
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_parentfragment,
                container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        final String text = bundle.getString("text");
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(text);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParentFragment parent = (ParentFragment) InitialContentFragment.this
                        .getParentFragment();
                parent.requestFragmentTransaction();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

As a side note, NEVER ignore the try-catch block like you did.

Comment: Ive implemented your code for Navigation Drawer using the following code.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678513/swapable-tabs-in-slider-menu-fragment and its working absolutely fine, but the problem when you click on the navigation drawer list fragment. The Tab host tabs are appearing and working awesome, but when go back to another activity and come back to the tab host activity. The tabs are appearing, but the linear layout background of the tab host is appearing as shown in the images below of tabhost clicked single and twice. i.stack.imgur.com/CzIsC.png    i.stack.imgur.com/Dmxn3.png

Comment: @B.rohitNare Please post a new question providing all of the details of your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483069/navigation-drawer-with-tabhost-and-viewpager @Luksprog
Hey mate follow the link

Comment: @Luksprog, But it seems that in your solution,  getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() always returns 0 ? any clue ?