# Navigation drawer with tabhost and viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

IVe implemented a Navigation drawer side menu with few fragments. For each fragment ive implemented different implementations. But for one fragment ive implemented `Tabhost` with `viewpager`. But the problem in facing is the `Tabhost` tabs content are visible on first click. But if you go back of the activity and come back to activity the tabs content are not visible. Instead of that `Tabhost` Linear Layout background is appearing.

MainActivity

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.content.res.Configuration;
  import android.content.res.TypedArray;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
  import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ListView;

  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ListView mDrawerList;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

 // nav drawer title
  private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
 private CharSequence mTitle;

 // slide menu items

 private String[] navMenuTitles;
 private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

 private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
 private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(5, -1)));

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                // accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                // accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_closeone);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    case R.id.logo:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new Home();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new News();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new Review();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new Theaters();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new Videos();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new Photos();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

ReviewFragment

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.TabHost;

 public class Review extends Fragment  {

 private TabHost mTabHost;
 private ViewPager mViewPager;
 private TabsPagerAdapter mTabsAdapter;


 public Review(){}

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.review_layout, container, false);

     return rootView;
 }  

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    mTabHost = (TabHost) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    Log.e("mTabHost", mTabHost + "");

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Log.e("mViewPager", mViewPager + "");
    mTabsAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mTabHost, mViewPager);

    // Here we load the content for each tab. 
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Audience").setIndicator("Audience"), AudienceFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Critics").setIndicator("Critics"), CriticsFragment.class, null);
    Log.e("mTabsAdapter", mTabsAdapter + "");
   /* 
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }*/
}   
}
```

TabsPagerAdapter

```
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.TabHost;
  import android.widget.TabWidget;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
private final Context mContext;
private final TabHost mTabHost;
private final ViewPager mViewPager;
private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

static final class TabInfo
{
    private final String tag;
    private final Class<?> clss;
    private final Bundle args;

    TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)
    {
        tag = _tag;
        clss = _class;
        args = _args;
    }
}

static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory
{
    private final Context mContext;

    public DummyTabFactory(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public View createTabContent(String tag)
    {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }
}

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager)
{
    super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    mContext = activity;
    mTabHost = tabHost;
    mViewPager = pager;
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}


public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
{
    tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

    TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
    mTabs.add(info);
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return mTabs.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);

    return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);

}

public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
{
    int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

}

public String getTag()
{           
    return mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
}

public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
{
     int pos = this.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
     this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(pos);
}

public void onPageSelected(int position)
{
    // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
    // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
    // The jerk.
    // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
    // ViewPager.
    TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
    int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
    widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
}

public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
{
}
}
```

Comment: In `TabsPagerAdapter` what `FragmentManager` are you using? I hope it is the o0ne returned by `getChildFragmentManager()` of the fragment.

Comment: @Luksprog nope its this one what im using
 super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
Cause the activity we using is FragmentActivity. So, it supports only getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: Change your adapter's constructor definition to `public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager, FragmentManager mgr){
    super(mgr);...`. Then in the fragment do `mTabsAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mTabHost, mViewPager, getChildFragmentManager());`.

Comment: @Luksprog Awesome mate its working absolutely fine with your constructor response. Thank a lot for the help mate

Comment: @B.rohitNare did you solved ?can you help me with this?

Comment: @Johnson Help you with what? Please post a new question providing all the details of your problem.

Comment: I am not allowing to post question here but my problem is same like..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106944/how-to-add-tabhost-with-navigation-drawer?noredirect=1#comment44592501_28106944

Comment: @Luksprog can you check it?

Comment: @Luksprog Can you help me out again with fragments. When im working with fragments  for implementing maps. Facing the following error, been through somuch research, unable to find right solution. Rather changing Fragment to FragmentActivity. I already posted my question, hope you can help me out with this error. Thank you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919792/illegal-argument-exception-working-with-google-maps-using-fragments